# Почему командная строка Visual Studio 2017 не может найти .h и .lib файлы, и как это исправить?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Комндная строка: x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream> 
int main() {return 0;}
```

Нужно скомпилировать `main.cpp` через командную строку:

```
$ cl /EHsc main.cpp
```

хоть `iostream` в этом примере и не требуется, но почему-то возникает ошибка:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: corecrt.h: No such file or directory

Ясно что нет там этого файла, но он ведь явно должен там быть.

Если уберу `#include <iostream>`, то возникает другая ошибка:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "libucrt.lib"

Comment: При чем тут командная строка? Вы знаете что такое компилятор? И как вы компилируете через командную строку? В смысле, какой командой?

Comment: Забыл указать, cl /EHsc main.cpp

Answer (score 1):

В этом то и дело, что этот файл там должен быть. Зайдите в `Visual Studio Installer`, затем справа увидете `Дополнительно`, нажмите на `Востановить`, ошибка должна исчезнуть. Возможно произошёл сбой и файлы были удалены, возможно, что маловероятно, вы не установили компоненты `C++`.

**Update:**
Зайдите в свойства проекта и выберите самую свежую версию `Target Platform Version(Версия целевой платформы)` судя по вашим скриншотам, это `10.0.17763.0`

Comment: нет, это не помогло (

Comment: @K2Re8, предоставьте скриншоты, что вы устанавливали в `Visual Studio Installer`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/oc7cxe
http://prntscr.com/oc7d8t
http://prntscr.com/oc7dgb
http://prntscr.com/oc7dlz
http://prntscr.com/oc7dv7

Comment: @K2Re8, поправил ответ исходя из ваших скриншотов

Comment: нету никакого проекта, только файл main.cpp и x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017.

Comment: @K2Re8, очень странно, я ведь правильно понимаю, что вы привели лишь код, как пример? Предоставьте рабочий код, с которым у вас и выходит данная ошибка. У меня всё прекрасно компилируется, в командной строке перехожу в каталог с `main.cpp`, далее ввожу `cl /EHsc main.cpp`, не каких ошибок на выходе нет, получаю обьектник.

Comment: @K2Re8, ещё как вариант, попробуйте создать пустой проект в самой студии, в свойствах проекта выставить последнюю `SDK`, сохранить его и попробовать откомпилировать через консоль. Если же и это не поможет, тогда придётся вам переустанавливать компоненты `C++ и SDK`, так как на лицо, у вас поломались связи.